# Batch File / Windows: Deleting Files with Number in File Extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, delete-file

I want to delete all files which contain a number in the file extension - in my case the files look like:

```
FileName.1
FileName.2
FileName.3
...
```

I (naively) tried `del *.*[0-9]*` but (of course) no luck. I am using a **Windows 7** system where I do not have administrator rights.

Just as an info - the question is related to a question of me in a Latex forum: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310238

---

**Thanks all for the answers.** It's hard for me to say which I should accept.

Comment: [PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell) is pre-installed on all Windows 7 systems. A PowerShell script will be so much easier to write than a Windows batch script. Would that be an option?

Comment: @IInspectable That would be ok!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that as follows:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "FILEMASK=%~1"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D "%FILEMASK%" ^| findstr /R "\.[0-9][0-9]*$"
') do (
    del /P /F "%%~F"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

To use this batch program, provide the file mask as an argument. If you do not give such, the current directory will be enumerated.

The `/P` switch at the `del` command is added for testing purposes, so if you do not want any prompts to appear, just remove it. The `/F` switch forces deletion of read-only files; if you do not want that, remove it too.

---

The file mask I am talking about above is for the `dir` command only, which supports the global wildcards `*` and `?` only, standing for a sequence of characters or a single character, respectively. See also this Microsoft article: [Using wildcard characters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490639.aspx).

There is no direct way to build a mask that matches numeric digits only, according also to this: [Command-prompt wildcards for digits?](https://superuser.com/questions/489939/command-prompt-wildcards-for-digits)

Therefore I am using the `findstr` command, which supports a tiny set of regular expressions, to filter any files that have got a purely numeric file extension. See the Microsoft article [Findstr](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) and also site [FINDSTR](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) for details about this useful command.

Comment: Can you give an example of the file mask? I am really a beginner.  Do you mean *. * for example?

Comment: If you want to delete all files in a certain directory, say `C:\TEMP`, then specify `C:\TEMP` or `C:\TEMP\*.*`; to address `.txt` files in the current directory, use `*.txt` or `.\*.txt`; the `*` means any number of any valid characters; you can use `?` to represent a single valid character, like `te?t.txt`, which would match `test.txt`, `text.txt` or `te0t.txt`, for example...

Comment: And thank you very much - this looks like a lot of effort. I will try it out.

Comment: In my case I want to delete all ***.number** - how would that look like?

Comment: The file mask I am talking about is only for the `dir` command, which only supports the wildcards `*` and `?`; the `findstr` command constitutes an additional filter for all the files returned by `dir`; so you could use `*.*`, which matches all files in the current directory; the `findstr` command searches for files ending with `.` followed by a number, so all this leads to the result you want to achieve... so in short: state `*.*`... I will update my answer to include more detail on this...

Answer (score 2):

This solution delete all files with a numeric extension greater than `0`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.*) do (
   set "ext=%%~Xa"
   set /A "ext=!ext:~1!"
   if !ext! neq 0 del "%%a"
)
```

To delete files in multiple folders, just add `/R` switch to `for` command.

Comment: Good idea, +1, although it will also delete files with extensions like `.1!` or `.!2`...

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use PowerShell (which comes with Windows 7), you can make use of regex patterns. One long form approach is:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem "d:\folder\" | where { $_.Extension -match '[0-9]' } | Remove-Item -Whatif
```

(That pattern will match extensions which contain a number, or use `'^\.\d+$'` to match extensions which are entirely numbers and nothing else. The `-WhatIf` flag makes it non-destructive so it tells you what it would remove, remove that flag to make it run for real).

There's a handful of ways to write this in short form, e.g.:

```powershell
gci "d:\folder\" |? { $_.Extension -match '\d' } | rm
```

Comment: Thank you very much - for both solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Having said that PowerShell is nicer, easier, and more powerful, if I had to do a batch file approach, it might be:

```
@Echo Off

rem List all filenames into a temp file
dir /b > tmpFileList.txt

rem Isolate filenames which end in numbers into another temp file
findstr /R "\.[0-9][0-9]*$" tmpFileList.txt > tmpFileList2.txt

rem Run through the second temp file, and delete those filenames
for /f "delims=" %%L in (tmpFileList2.txt) do (
    del /P "%%L"
)

rem cleanup
rm tmpFileList.txt
rm tmpFileList2.txt
```

Remove the `/P` to delete without prompting.

You could probably do this without one or more of the temporary files, but this is straightforward enough. However this will only work if all the files are in one folder, and you are in the same folder. (The PowerShell version is easier to make it work with sub-folders).

[Edit: adjusted the 'for' loop so it can handle files with spaces in the name]